# Post API call in C# console application should be cognito authorized in API Gateway

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a POST api in AWS API Gateway which posts data to dynamodb, I am accessing the API from C# console application. Now I need to authorize this web api call using cognito user pools.

What is the best way to do authorize a web api from C#? How should I do it?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication.html

Comment: Firstly, you need to authenticate your identity from User Pool. Then there will be token issued to you. Use that token when calling AWS API.

Comment: But I can authenticate only by hardcoding username and password in the code right? Is there any other way without leaving username and password open in the code. ?

Comment: There are ways you can store encrypted username and passwords in configuration files. (eg: web.config)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this use-case, you should procure a JWT Token from your Cognito User Pool. This JWT Token can be used to avert an HTTP 401 Response for your REST API in AWS API Gateway.

Since you would not like the Cognito credentials dictionary to be hardcoded in your code, you could leverage a managed AWS security service like SSM Parameter Store or Secrets Manager, and make AWS SigV4 API calls to retrieve strings as necessary. Additionally, you can also make use of the OAuth 2.0 compliant [AUTHORIZATION](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html) and [TOKEN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html) endpoints that Cognito provides, to make use to HTTP requests only instead of relying on programmatic APIs.